# Adding alias to end of alias list in .bashrc file using sed

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that I want to add an `alias` to the end of the `alias` list in the `.bashrc` file. I'm thinking something with `sed` would work, just not sure how to find the last line that begins with `alias`, then add on the next line another `alias`.

Comment: please give an example input and desired output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why do you need to add it to an "alias list"? If you don't have additional requirements that you did not specify in the question, just append your alias to `.bashrc`:

```
echo "alias youralias='yourcmd'" >> /home/user/.bashrc
```

Comment: Often, .bashrc loads .alias - making it even more obvious, but the end of .bashrc works, too.

Answer (score 4):

When I hear "do something after the last whatever", I think of reversing the file and do something when I see the first whatever:

```
tac .bashrc | 
awk -v newalias="alias new=foo" '$1 == "alias" {print newalias} 1' | 
tac > .bashrc.new
mv .bashrc .bashrc.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) && mv .bashrc.new .bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is much easier/cleaner to do in Perl, Python, etc.

But if you must use sed, here's a starting point:

```
$ sed -ne ':START
/alias/b ALIASES
p
b
:ALIASES
p
n
/alias/b ALIASES
i \
alias foo=bar
:REST
p
n
b REST
' < aliases > aliases.new
$ diff -u aliases aliases.new
--- aliases     2011-04-07 08:30:30.000000000 +1000
+++ aliases.new 2011-04-07 08:34:09.000000000 +1000
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@

 alias a=apple
 alias b=banana
+alias foo=bar

 echo something else
$ mv aliases.new aliases
```

A fuller version that works for me is

```
$ name=b
$ replacement=barney
sed -i.bak -n -e '
:START
/^[[:space:]]*alias/ b NEXTALIAS
# not an alias, print it as-is and go to next line
p
b
:NEXTALIAS
# start processing this alias line
/^[[:space:]]*alias[[:space:]][[:space:]]*'"$name"'/ b REPLACE
/^[[:space:]]*alias/ b PRINT

# found the end of the alias block, insert the alias here
:INSERT
# grab the indentation back from the hold space
x
s/$/alias '"$name='$replacement'"'/
p
x
b REST

:PRINT
# remember how the last alias line was indented...
h
s/^\([[:space:]]*\).*/\1/
x
# ... and print the line
p
n
b NEXTALIAS

:REPLACE
# we found an existing alias with a matching name, replace it
# I add single quotes around replacement so that the caller can write
# replacement='echo something' rather than replacement="'echo something'"
s/\(.*\)alias[[:space:]][[:space:]]*'"$name"'.*/\1alias '"$name='$replacement'"/'
b REST

:REST
# we made it past the aliases block, just print the remaining lines
p
n
b REST
' aliases

$ diff -u aliases.bak aliases
--- aliases.bak 2011-04-07 09:09:26.000000000 +1000
+++ aliases     2011-04-07 09:11:05.000000000 +1000
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 echo blah

 alias a=apple
-alias b=banana
+alias b='barney'
 alias c=carrot

 echo something else
```

Note that there are some edge cases I have not handled explicitly.  For example, what should happen if there are two blocks of aliases?  What if there is a commented out alias in the middle of the alias block, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is the tool to use if you can't use better scripting language. There's no need to use sed`

```
awk 'FNR==NR&&/alias/{s=FNR;next}FNR==s{ $0=$0"\nalias=new alias\n"}NR>FNR' .bashrc .bashrc > temp && mv temp .bashrc
```